# Count issue in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query as follows:

```
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
           SELECT *
    FROM   (SELECT [id],
                   [account],
                   [tag],
                   [location],
                   [whoAdded],
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY whoAdded ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
            FROM   accountLogAccounts) AS a
    WHERE  rn = 1
    FOR    XML PATH ('users'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
END
END
```

I am trying to include a count in here of the total number of accounts for the user as well as all the tags.

The table looks like:

```
id, account, tag, whoAdded
1, 123, dog, bob
2, 123, cat, jon
3, 125, pig, bob
```

Expected result:

User Bob has 2 distinct accounts and 2 tags

User jon has 1 distinct account and 1 tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select count(distinct whoAdded), count(distinct tag), whoadded
FROM accountLogAccounts
group by whoadded
```

should return

```
2, 2, bob
1, 1, jon
```

if you need the actual text, apply string concatenation accordingly.